# how to add keys of a NSMutableArray into another array?

Tags: ios, nsmutablearray

I have a `NSMutableArray` like this.

```
2015-09-22 10:12:22.739 amigo[17198:6080591] Headers ************************ (
    {
    BidAcceptanceRide = 0;
    BidRejectionRide = 1;
    BidRide = 1;
    BookingCancellationByBuyer = 0;
    BookingCancellationBySeller = 0;
    BookingConfirmation = 3;
    BookingRemainder = 0;
    Review = 0;
    TotalNotification = 5;
}

)
```

What I want to do is check these each key value pairs and if the value is greater than 0 I want to add its key to another array. How can I do this? Please help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with following `code` and you can modify it as per your need.

```
  NSArray * arrHeaders; // Your existing array in which you have value.
    NSMutableArray * arrSortedData = [NSMutableArray array]; // New array in which you will add data.


    for (int i = 0; i < [arrHeaders count]; i++){

        NSDictionary * dicTeamp = [arrHeaders objectAtIndex:i];

        NSMutableDictionary * dicSortedData = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary]; // Dictionary where all keys and value which is greater than 0.

        for (int j = 0; j < [[dicTeamp allKeys] count]; j++){

            if([[dicTeamp valueForKey:[[dicTeamp allKeys] objectAtIndex:j]] intValue] > 0){
                [dicSortedData setValue:[dicTeamp valueForKey:[[dicTeamp allKeys] objectAtIndex:j]] forKey:[[dicTeamp allKeys]objectAtIndex:j]];
            }
        }
        [arrSortedData addObject:dicSortedData];
    }

    NSLog(@"Your sorted data = %@",arrSortedData);
```